# How to check which "applications are keeping the volume busy" on Linux?

Tags: linux, mount, disk, usb-drive, unmounting

Sometimes after I read and write files in a USB connected to my linux desktop, then turn off all visible applications, wait for my USB to stop blinking, then attempt to eject the USB, I get a warning `One or more applications are keeping the volume busy`. It is strange since there is nothing on the foreground and all operations regarding it should have ended as the USB stopped blinking. How can I find what is occupying the USB, preventing it from being removed?

Comment: like, if you look at the list of potentially related questions (which you, by the way, were also presented before you submitted the question, there's multiple duplicates of this question. Doing your own research is expected!

Comment: It may be that you need to press the eject button from your file manager, because even if the job seems to be complete, the system may delay physically writing data.